# Formatting a cell in way so that only values specific format can be entered

Tags: excel, excel-2010, xlsxwriter

I am using excel to store some data. The column stores some kind of output id which has to be in a certain format . The string should be in the format FP-2#-#### for example FP-22-1234 should be valid something like px423 should not be valid and the user should not be allowed to enter.

I know in SQL you can achieve this . How would I achieve this in excel

Thanks

Used conditional formatting and data validation but its not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT` and `ISNUMBER` combinations as formula for custom Data validation..

Something like this (assuming that you're adding data validation to cell `A1`):

```
=AND(LEFT(A1; 4)="FP-2"; AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1;5;1))); AND(MID(A1;6;1)="-"; ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1; 4))))))
```

to make it a bit more readable (and understandable), multiline formula:

```
=AND(
    LEFT(A1;4) = "FP-2";
    AND(
        ISNUMBER(
            VALUE(
                MID(A1;5;1)
            )
        );
        AND(
            MID(A1;6;1) = "-";
            ISNUMBER(
                VALUE(
                    RIGHT(A1;4)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```